# Test Parse application

Tags: android, unit-testing, parse-platform

I am using Parse with my Android application, and I didn't understand how to test it.

I have looked at [this](https://parse.com/questions/testing-android-apps-that-use-the-parse-api) solution for testing Parse.
I have created two servers, one for production and one for testing. My app is configured to work with the production server on normal run, and with the testing server when I run it in testing mode. That's works just fine.

The problem is that I don't understand how to make Parse testable and make the tests independent. For example: If my test saves some items in the testing Parse server, how can I clear them before the next test?

How can I create independent tests using Parse and make my app testable when I use Parse?

Comment: Ah ha! Great question but this is a deep and far reaching question. Not really stackoverflow material. Better to show us some code of what tests you have attempted and how they are not "independent" or how something isn't "testable"

Comment: I don't really know how to show example. Each test interacts with the database (create / delete / search), and the state of the database after the modifications stays the same for the next tests.

Comment: The trick is that you should write unit tests that don't use a database, in this case don't use Parse. Create an interface for your data persistence, 1 implementation would be Parse, another would be a mock in memory persistance. This is called Hexagonal Architecture

Comment: But how can I test that the `save` method (for example) is working when I am using Parse? I mean, when I use the memory as DB, it is not have the limitations of Parse. The real situation: we decided to create abstraction layer in the app, that will create good separation between the app and Parse. How can we test this abstraction layer? We must test it with Parse...

Comment: if you test parse it would be an integration test, perhaps with Espresso, but these tests don't have much value. i.e. why test that Parse works its not your product. However if you did do this you could create a debug only screen that has a button to erase all database data, then write into the test setup clicking of this button

Comment: It is not really testing Parse. It should test if our "Save" operation is working fine with Parse. The button in debug only screen is a good idea (and we think about it), but how can we implement such button? How can I write the code that clears the Parse database (we didn't find any way to do this)?